# ProviderException while creating MediaFileInfo object in Kentico

Tags: model-view-controller, thumbnails, kentico, media-library

I want to get thumbnail from file in Kentico 8.2, so I use method as below:

```
private void ThumbnailTest()
{
    var siteInfo = SiteInfoProvider.GetSiteInfo(ConfigUtils.Tribes.SiteId);
    MediaLibraryInfo libraryInfo = MediaLibraryInfoProvider.GetMediaLibraryInfo(ConfigUtils.Tribes.MediaLibraryID);

    string filePath = string.Format(@"D:\\Kentico\{0}\{1}\Homepage\{2}", siteInfo.SiteName, libraryInfo.LibraryFolder, "top_banner_1.jpg");
    MediaFileInfo fileInfo = new MediaFileInfo(filePath, libraryInfo.LibraryID, libraryInfo.LibraryFolder); // <-- exception occurs here

    var thumbnail = MediaFileInfoProvider.GetImageThumbnail(fileInfo, ConfigUtils.Tribes.MediaLibraryPath, ConfigUtils.Tribes.SiteName);
}
```

but exception occurs while creating MediaFileInfoObject.

> System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException: Method is only
>   supported if the user name parameter matches the user name in the
>   current Windows Identity.

I use Kentico as a content platform on remote server 'A' and I want to get thumbnail for MVC application from my localhost.

Why this exception occurs and what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for the suggestions!

**UPDATE 1:**

MediaFileInfo object searches directory at localhost, but not path at remote server and think this is the main issue.

My application is separate MVC website which needs to get thumbnail of image from other domain (server).

**UPDATE 2:**

```
private void ThumbnailTest()
{
    MediaLibraryInfo libraryInfo = MediaLibraryInfoProvider.GetMediaLibraryInfo(ConfigUtils.Tribes.MediaLibraryID);
    var mediaFileInfo = MediaFileInfoProvider.GetMediaFileInfo(libraryInfo.LibraryID, "Homepage/top_banner_1.jpg"); // success here, file found!
    var thumbnail = MediaFileInfoProvider.GetImageThumbnail(mediaFileInfo, ConfigUtils.Tribes.MediaLibraryPath, ConfigUtils.Tribes.SiteName, 300, 200, 500); // <-- null occurs here 
}
```

I'm confused, because according to Kentico documentation method GetImageThumbnail:

> Returns image thumbnail from the disk or create a new one if doesn't
>   exist yet.

And I have no idea, why thumbnail is null. It should at least create new thumbnail. Should I now use solution provided by @user6043336 ?

Comment: Have you added any role providers to your web.config?

Comment: No, I haven't added any role providers into web.config. Is it necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imho you shouldn`t create new MediaFileInfo like

```
MediaFileInfo fileInfo = new MediaFileInfo(filePath, libraryInfo.LibraryID, libraryInfo.LibraryFolder); // <-- exception occurs here
```

but you should try to get media info from db or fs (depending on your setting) instead. Try to use

```
GetMediaFileInfo(int mediaLibraryId, string mediaFilePath)
```

from *MediaFileInfoProvider* class.

ad. UPDATE 2:

I`ve checked internal implementation on source code and it returns null **only if** fileInfo is null or if object on filePath does not exists. Please double check it.

Answer (score 0):

What is the code part of (web part, module, event, etc.)?

Anyway, you should call the **SetMediaFileInfo** method before you get the thumbnail. Below is the whole code example of creating a media file in Kentico 8.2:

```
private bool CreateMediaFile()
{
    // Prepare the parameters
    string filePath = "~/CMSAPIExamples/Code/Tools/MediaLibrary/Files/Powered_by_kentico2.gif";

    // Get media library
    MediaLibraryInfo library = MediaLibraryInfoProvider.GetMediaLibraryInfo("MyNewLibrary", SiteContext.CurrentSiteName);
    if (library != null)
    {
        // Create new media file object
        MediaFileInfo mediaFile = new MediaFileInfo(Server.MapPath(filePath), library.LibraryID);

        // Create file info
        FileInfo file = FileInfo.New(Server.MapPath(filePath));
        if (file != null)
        {
            // Set the properties
            mediaFile.FileName = "MyNewFile";
            mediaFile.FileTitle = "My new file title";
            mediaFile.FileDescription = "My new file description.";
            mediaFile.FilePath = "MyNewFolder/MyNewFile.gif";
            mediaFile.FileExtension = file.Extension;
            mediaFile.FileMimeType = "image/gif";
            mediaFile.FileSiteID = SiteContext.CurrentSiteID;
            mediaFile.FileLibraryID = library.LibraryID;
            mediaFile.FileSize = file.Length;

            // Create the media file
            MediaFileInfoProvider.SetMediaFileInfo(mediaFile);

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```